# ngClass Directive: Can I use multiple expressions to add multiple classes?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Here is an example of what I want to achieve

```
data-ng-class="{ 'tooltip_show' : showTooltip , 'tooltip__' + brand.settings.name }"
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why there are two values inside one ng-class for 'tooltip_show' ?

Comment: I need have one class which depends on showTooltip, and other which depends on this variable brand.settings.name. Can i do this in another way?

Comment: As @harriyot mentioned . this should suffice { 'tooltip_show' : showTooltip , 'tooltip__' + brand.settings.name : tooltipText }

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: What is happening? Do you get any errors? Can you post more code on how you are trying to achieve this?

Comment: <div class="tooltip" data-ng-click="toogleTooltip()" data-ng-class="{ 'tooltip_show' : showTooltip , 'tooltip__' + brand.settings.name : tooltipText }"></div> . I didn't get any errors. I only receive first class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the array form for `ng-class`:

```
<div ng-class="[showTooltip ? 'tooltip_show' : '',
                'tooltip__' + brand.settings.name]">
<div>
```

OR compute the class in JavaScript:

```
<div ng-class="computeClass(tooltip_show, brand.setting.name)">
</div>
```

```
$scope.computeClass(show, name) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.showTooltip = show;
    obj['tooltip_'+name] = true;
    return obj;
};
```

The later approach is more easily debugged and better for complex computation.

See also,

- [AngularJS ng-class Directive Reference - Known Issues](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass#known-issues)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#embedding-interpolation-markup-inside-expressions)

Comment: Yeah this is what I think you can do @стас Пилипко, nice answer georgeawg :+1:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't set a value for the second item. Did you mean something like

```
{ 'tooltip_show' : showTooltip , 'tooltip__' + brand.settings.name : tooltipText }
```

or

```
{ 'tooltip_show' : showTooltip , 'tooltip__' : brand.settings.name }
```

?

Comment: 'tooltip__' + brand.settings.name - when i write only this part, i receive somerthing like this class="tooltip__class". brand.settings.name - it is variable and depends on the page.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/genaqapefe/edit?html,js,output

```
data-ng-class="{ 'tooltip_show': showToolTip, {{ 'tooltip_' + brand.settings.name }}: true }"
```

This is working for me in this bin. I couldn't get it to evaluate without the curly braces, although not sure if that's the best practice.

Comment: @ стас Пилипко or did you want it to always show that? You could just use a class, like: `class="{{ 'tooltip_' + brand.settings.name }}" data-ng-class="{ 'tooltip_show': showToolTip }"`

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Why mixing interpolation and expressions is bad practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#embedding-interpolation-markup-inside-expressions)

Comment: You should not use interpolation in the value of the `class` attribute, when using the `ngClass` directive on the same element. See [AngularJS ng-class Directive Reference - Known Issues](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass#known-issues).

Comment: @georgeawg yeah, you're right. I think a better answer to this question would probably be to restructure how the property is built to begin with. As in, not in the HTML but maybe in the Javascript.